# Multiple offset y-axis AND multiple offset x-axis for same subplot (at least 3 of each)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I would like to plot data of various scales on the same axes object. This means having multiple x and y-axis on the same 'axes' object (I'm aware there are other ways to visualise multi-scale data but I don't want to get into the details too much of why I need to do it this way!).

I understand how to use `twinx` to get multiple y-axis on the same plot using the "[Multiple Yaxis With Spines" matplotlib demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.4.3/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html). However, in this example all the data share the same x-axis. I want to have both multiple y-axis and multiple x-axis. Having 2 of each is trivial: I can simply use `twin_ax = ax.twinx().twiny()`. However, if I want more than two x-axis and y-axis, I need a way to offset both x-axis and y-axis spines. The problem is that if I use `ax.twinx().twiny()`, I can only offset the top spine and not the right spine. If I use `ax.twiny().twinx()`, then it's the other way round.

Here's my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

twin1 = ax.twinx().twiny()
twin2 = ax.twinx().twiny()

twin2.spines.right.set_position(("axes", 1.2))
twin2.spines.top.set_position(("axes", 1.2))

plt.show()
```

It appears that only the top spine gets offset, not the right spine. If I swap the ordering to `twin2 = ax.twiny().twinx()`, then only the right spine gets offset and not the right! How do I fix this problem?

Comment: So `twin1` and `twin2` are just 2 new axes superposed on top of the first `ax`? This idea of `twinx` is to create a new Y-independent axis, the same for `twiny` (X-independent). So here `twin1` and `twin2` would be both X and Y independent right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ax.twinx()` creates a new axis `ax2` *from scratch*, superimposed on `ax`. [See here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/b3bd929cf07ea35479fded8f739126ccc39edd6d/lib/matplotlib/axes/_base.py#L4436-L4464).

In the rest of the method, you'll see that `ax2` Y ticks are modified so they display on the right.

On top of this `ax.twinx()` (i.e `ax2`), you create `twin2` by calling the `.twiny()` method - which also creates a new axis *from scratch*, superimposed with the other axes.

This new `twin2` axis does not have Y-ticks on the right (`ax2` does), so when you set the position of the spine, it works but it does not show the ticks and the labels.

You can use the following function on the twins axes to obtain the results you want

```
def prepare_twin(ax, offset=0):
    ax.yaxis.set_visible(True)
    
    ax.yaxis.tick_right()
    ax.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
    ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('right')

    ax.spines.right.set_position(("axes", offset))
    ax.spines.top.set_position(("axes", offset))
```

In your code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(constrained_layout=True)

twin1 = ax.twinx().twiny()
twin2 = ax.twinx().twiny()

prepare_twin(twin1, offset=1.2)
prepare_twin(twin2, offset=1.4)
```

[image]

Notes:

- This function does not work anymore if you create `twin1` and `twin2` with `ax.twiny().twinx()` (switch order).
- In this process, 5 overlapping axes have been created, not 3.